# auditd-like software for Windows?

Tags: windows, audit, logging

I need to know how to log users and admins activity on Windows, like auditd does on Linux. After searching, the only thing I found was this [Audit account log-on events policy option](http://www.jabis.ro/2012/4/0304012012.pdf) for Windows 7.

Is there some standard used for Windows servers and workstations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging options available in Windows run pretty deep, so choose what you want and set your policies appropriately.

To give you a flavour of what options there are (and are recommended) have a look at the [Audit Policy Recommendations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/audit-policy-recommendations).

Comment: So no specific tool, everything is available inside Windows itself and it is just a matter of configuration?